# How do you change views from a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an app that consists of a Tab Bar Controller that points to 3 view controllers (all with tabs). In one of these tab views I've made a button and I want it to open a new view (without a tab at the bottom). This new view would need a navigation bar with a back button to return to the previous view, so I was thinking I need to create a navigation controller?

Essentially this is what I'm trying to do (I apologize for the poorly drawn diagram).
[image]

How can I get this new view (entirely independent of the tab bar controller) to display programatically? Would this require a navigation controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a presented view controller. Call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

I very frequently do this with a navigation bar and a Back or Done button, just as you describe. But it's not a navigation controller or navigation interface; it's just a convenient way of showing the user how to get back.

For example, this is a presented view in one of my apps. The top is a navigation bar, and the `cancel` button gets us back (call `dismissViewController...`). The rest is a scrolling view (a UICollectionView) of buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[myTabBar setSelectedIndex:1]
```

You may have to access the `tabBar` like `self.tabBarController` so… `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

`1` is `index 1` in the tabbar's stack (this is like tapping a `tabBar` button manually)

Comment: Well the problem I am facing is that the new view I want to display is entirely independent from the Tab Bar Controller because I don't want it to display a tab bar at the bottom

Comment: You need to add a navigation controller that controls the view then. You can add it on storyboards or create a new one using code. This will give you the back button, etc... Alternatively you could just hide the tabbar [tabBar setHidden: YES] (along those lines)